# How to change to a view controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I want to transition to a view I made in the `main.storyboard`, when they enter the password correctly.

How do I do this?

I need it to pull up the view I already created. I want a transition in the code block `-(void) unlock`.

---

#### Code

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Login
//
//  Created by Ben Rosen on 5/24/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ben Rosen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UnlockedScreen.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    
    NSString *correctUser = @"money";
    NSString *correctPassword = @"ilovemoney";

    if ((usernameTextField.text == correctUser)==YES && (passwordTextField.text = correctPassword)==YES)
    {
        [self unlock];
    }
   
}

-(void) unlock
{
    // here should be the transition
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```

Comment: This question is a bit too general. Are you using UINavigationController? Do you use segue? Without know the structure of your app, it is hard to recommend you anything.

Comment: I have 2 ViewControllers, the first one has an entry to enter a passcode. When the passcode is entered, and login is clicked, it transitions to the actual view. I don't have a way to transition it, that is what I am wondering. I am not using UINavigationController. I just want it to have a modal transition.

Comment: Just follow Matteo Gobbi's answer below, I believe you will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `storyboard`, go on your **first view controller**, press **CTRL** click on the `viewController` and **release** the mouse (and CTRL) on the **destination view controller**.

Now **choose type of segue** (`push` if you are in a `navigationController` otherwise `modal`) and **choose an identifier** on the inspector **for this trigger**.

[image]

In your code:

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{

    NSString *correctUser = @"money";
    NSString *correctPassword = @"ilovemoney";

    if ([usernameTextField.text isEqualToString:correctUser] && [passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:correctPassword])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"name" sender:sender];
    }

}
```

As you see i changed your if statement..your compare was wrong.

Comment: I get the error: No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector performSequeWithIdentifier in this code: -(void) unlock
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"oneTransition"];
}

Comment: The method is: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"name" sender:sender]; See my answer update

Comment: Thanks. That worked. And one more thing, under my if statement, it says "comparison between point and integer". ('NSString *' and 'int')

Comment: oh my God i read now your if statement XD! See the update if statement in my answer and please, then select the answer as right because you wrote "Thanks. That worked."

Answer (score 1):

```
[self unlock];
```

remove it and write this method

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileSegue" sender:self] ;
```

in the storyboard name to identifier(profileSegue) on the inspector

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profileSegue"]) {
      ProfileViewController *profileViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      profileViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
      profileViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate your viewController with the identifier you have provided for your viewController.

```
-(void) unlock
{
    // here should be the transition
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardname" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllersID"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```